# How to get test credentials for Sagepay for developers

Tags: opayo

I have heared that sagepay provides only test credentials to merchant with Live credentials. As I am developer I need test credentials of sage pay to check the payment gateway?

I tried it using Simulator but unfortunately I get 500 Internal Server error on return from successfull payment of the gateway.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use **sagepaylabs3** if you want. Log in to MSP with username: **testuser** password: **testuser**

Comment: I'm not surprised - it was 2 1/2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Opayo (formerly SagePay) now have published test credentials that may be used. Find them at https://www.opayolabs.co.uk/apis/pi?content=pi-test-sandbox